# notices appearing when trying to write query using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Below I have a code where I am trying to run a query using mysqli.

```
 if (isset($_POST['module']))
    {
        $query = "SELECT ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleId = ?";

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); //line 99

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['module'] );

        if ( $stmt->execute() )
        {   
            $stmt->bind_result($moduleno, $modulename); 

            $stmt->fetch();

}
    }
```

Problem is that it is giving me these two undefined errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in ... on line 99 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ... on line 99
```

My question is what is causing the two errors in mysqli code as I don't see a problem with the code I have compiled.

Comment: show where you're setting `$mysqli`

Comment: @AaronW. Im a idiot, I know why it doesn't work, I have forgot to connect to the database as this script was the only php script which didn't have a connection to the database. Put it as your answer and I will mark it. Im an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're setting `$mysqli` properly in your script.